# Convert Hexadecimal C Array to Matlab Vector

Tags: c, arrays, matlab, hex

I am looking for a simple way to convert from c-code hex array to matlab

**Available C-Code Format:**
const uint16_t AUDIO_SAMPLE[] = {0x4952, 0x4646, 0x4f6e, 0xf, 0x4157, 0x4556, 0x6d66, 0x2074, 0x12, 0, 0x1}

**Required Matlab Format:**
AUDIO_SAMPLE = [18770 17990 20334 15 16727 17750 28006 8308 18 0 1]

Though it is simple to convert for small numbers, I have to convert a very big array. I am using embedded platform so the numbers can not be written to a simple text file for later read in matlab. Its preferable to write the conversion code in matlab.

**Edit:**

Till now able to get rid of **0x**. Failed to get a vector after using eval function as given below:

```
a='0x4952, 0x4646, 0x4f6e'; %Given
b = strrep(a, '0x', '') ; %Returns 4952, 4646, 4f6e
x = eval( [ '[', b, ']' ] ) %
```

Comment: Do you want to extract the values from C source code/header files?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Actually I have an audio clip given as c-code for a microcontroller. I needed to perform signal processing on it in Matlab. Later I might need to do the reverse too, i.e. conver matlab vector to C-Array.

Comment: Is it a one-off or do you need to do this many times?

Comment: At present its one time.

Comment: If you have source-code, how is the question related to "embedded"? That is a simple file-conversion on the host! Use Python to convert the file. Iif required only once, just strip off the C-stuff, leaving the comma-seperated values, then feed to the Python program.

Comment: As embedded development platforms are not supposed to handle data files on hard disk, I wanted to do all the conversions inside Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It proved tougher than I thought.

**Contents of the text file *audio.c***

```
4952, 4646, 0x4f6e, 0xf, 0x4157, 0x4556, 0x6d66, 0x2074, 0x12, 0, 0x1, 
0x2, 0xbb80, 0, 0xee00, 0x2, 0x4, 0x10, 0, 0x6166, 0x7463, 0x4, 
0, 0xd3cf, 0x3, 0x6164, 0x6174, 0x4f3c, 0xf, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

The given file has 11 values in each line. Here follows the MATLAB code to convert HEX values to decimal numbers:

```
fp = fopen('audio.c', 'rt');
C = textscan(fp, '%s', 'CommentStyle', '#', 'Delimiter', '');
fclose(fp);

C = regexp(C{:}, '\w+', 'match');
C = cellfun(@(x)strrep(x,'0x',''), C, 'UniformOutput', false);
C = cellfun(@(x)hex2dec(x), C, 'UniformOutput', false);
result=cell2mat(C)'
allOneString = sprintf('%d, ' , result)
```

Finally I have string of decimal values separated by comma as follows:

```
18770, 17990, 20334, 15, 16727, 17750, 28006, 8308, 18, 0, 1, 2, 48000, 0, 60928, 2, 4, 16, 0, 24934, 29795, 4, 0, 54223, 3, 24932, 24948, 20284, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Of course previous posts on SO were of immense help :)

Answer (score 1):

Copy the code that defines the array to a file called "clip.h".

Write a small c program that `#include "clip.h"` and use a simple loop to write the data in the desired format. Run the program on your desktop computer. It could look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "clip.h"
#define NUMBERS_PER_LINE 20

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int sample_length = (sizeof AUDIO_SAMPLE)/(sizeof AUDIO_SAMPLE[0]);

    printf("AUDIO_SAMPLE = [ ");
    for (i=0; i < sample_length; i++) {
        printf("%" PRIu16 PRId16, AUDIO_SAMPLE[i]);  // Use the format specifier for uint16_t.
        if (i % NUMBERS_PER_LINE == NUMBERS_PER_LINE - 1) {
            // Insert line continuation mark
            printf(" ...\n  ");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program will write the matlab code on stdout, so you need to redirect it to the desired file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Perhaps you missed later part of my post. Now I have to search how uVision can write to a text file or search a small kind enough c-compiler :)